# Error when trying to convert lyr to qml

Tags: qgis, convert, layer-file, qml

I am trying to convert a lyr file created for ArcGIS to qml in order to use it in QGIS. I installed the SLYR Community Edition Plugin version 5.0.0 in QGIS version 3.28.8-Firenze, provided the input file in lyr format and the location to store the output file in qml format.

The conversion failed, and the conversion log file gave the following error:

> raise UnsupportedVersionException(
> slyr_community.parser.exceptions.UnsupportedVersionException: Cannot
> read MaplexOverposterLayerProperties version 21, only support
> version(s): 22

Is 'MaplexOverposterLayerProperties' a property of the lyr file, and is there a method for changing it from version 21 to version 22?